# UK boy's comic story, 1960's, kids with special powers

Tags: story-identification, comics

As described in the header, I'm trying to remember the weekly story.

There were five or six kids, they regularly met at a  secret cave or grotto on some bleak windswept moor in England.
There was a pool in it, a drink of this gave you special powers for a few hours.

Enhanced speed, strength, stamina, vision and others I don't recall.

Being a typical boy's comic of the time, the nearby town they lived in had massive crime waves, just so these kids could catch a villain a week and hand them over to the police.

The 'something' imps (or similar) rings a faint bell.

Edit: I used to read a lot of different UK comics, Victor, Hotspur, rover, Beezer, Beano, dandy, ranger, and others.. awkward to say which one I used to read this in.
Black and White, typically 3 to 4 pages, sometimes a two week story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Inky Top Imps](http://www.internationalhero.co.uk/i/inkytop.htm)*, appearing in [*Topper*](https://britishcomics.fandom.com/wiki/Topper) issues #741–814 (1967-68) and #955-978 (1971)

[image: Panel from *The Inky Top Imps*]

> **History:** "In the village of Arkside in Arkdale live six close chums.
>   The youngsters have a secret hide-out in a cave high on Inky-Top Hill which
>   rises above Arkdale, and so they call themselves the Inky-Top Imps." The
>   cave has a hidden entrance behind a hinged stone. In the cavern behind is
>   a spring of special water. One gulp of the strange liquid gives the drinker
>   some fantastic powers he did not normally possess.
>
> Charlie gains superhuman strength when he drinks the water; Tommy can "run
>   like a deer" and "swim and dive like a seal"; Tubby becomes a fearless rock
>   climber; Lanky can "out-jump any kangaroo." In the case of the two girls,
>   I don't know what special powers they get from drinking the water. When Tubby's
>   Gran'dad McPherson accidentally drank it, he gained superhuman strength.

Found by searching for *british comic imps* and reading through the results got me the entry for *Topper*, wherein I searched for "imp" and found the name of the gang. One Google search of that name later got me the text and image above.